# What are the best REST endpoint for the same resource with two operations?

Tags: api-design, endpoint, rest

I have one resource `/foo` that has some variations.

On the "foo" page I can save an "foo" and submit an "foo". If I save, I can change/update it and submit, if I submit, I can't update anymore.

What are the endpoints that I can use for this?

I'm thinking about:

`POST /foo` Save an "foo";

`PUT /foo/:id` Update an "foo";

But what can I do to submit an "foo" that have been saved previously and what I can do if it is submitted without a previous save?

Comment: you should have an additional endpoint `POST /foo/:id/submit` to update a status in `foo` indicating it is submitted. Your other two endpoints can be used to `save` and `update`

Comment: So why are you not just checking the database on the backend if the data already exists for the specified id and either create a new record if it doesn't exist or update an existing one? You don't need two separate endpoints. If you're creating a new record, the id parameter isn't going to be specified, as you've already indicated that.

Comment: I'm thinking to follow this idea @Sante, but the problem is if I fill the form and submit, without save, I do not have an id, so I need to do two requests, like `POST /foo` and than `POST /foo/:id/submit` right?

Comment: Your backend realizes that you haven't provided an id and creates one for you and returns this in the response (if you need it in your client app). I do that all the time.

Comment: I don't like the idea of single endpoint to `create` and `update` a resource. I think you should handle which endpoint call based on state of the resource in the client side, ie: existance of `id` field

Comment: I have one field that indicates if it is submitted or not, "submitDate", I'm doing this:

`POST /foo` if is submit date present, submit it, else, save;

`PUT /foo/:id` if is submit date present, submit it, else, save;

The submitDate is inserted when someone clicks on the submit button.

This makes more sense for me, seams that are more REST compliant.